# What does "flickery" mean as a noun?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "flickery" mean here? Is it some sort of movie?

> Twenty million Montags running, running like an ancient **flickery Keystone Comedy**, cops, robbers, chasers and the chased. hunts and the hunted, he had seen it a thousand times.

Comment: Why do you think it's a noun? It's an adjective that modifies "Keystone Comedy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Flickery” is an adjective, meaning [“seeming to flicker; unsteady”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flickery)

Movies of that era ([Keystone Studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_Studios) operated from 1912 to 1917) had many technical issues that caused the [image to flicker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Orde7FtHh0).